# mosquitto and activemq mtt bridge not working

Tags: activemq-classic, mqtt, mosquitto

Am currently developing an application with mosquitto and activemq.
one device will publish the message to mosquitto and forward that to activemq and publish the message. there are multiple subscribers for activemq.
so am using mosquitto bridge. but it's not working below is the code.both mosquitto and active may exists in the same machine also.

```
connection testmq
bridge_insecure false
address localhost:1893
cleansession false
clientid 1
start_type automatic
username system
password manager
notifications false
try_private true
topic dev1 in 2 owntracks/ac/ owntracks/ac/
topic dev2 out 2 owntracks/mq/ owntracks/mq/
```

Please provide me any suggestions

Comment: What exactly isn't working? What action are you taking and what result do you expect that you're not seeing?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add
`bridge_protocol_version mqttv311`
to your mosquitto configuration. It helped me to setup a basic connection between mosquitto and AMQ.

It would be much better if you added some more information about your issue. Just "not working" is not enough. Do you have any informative messages about the connection state either in AMQ or mosquitto log?